# Call a SignarR Hub from kendo upload instead of a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, kendo-upload

I'm evaluating KendoUI upload widget to upload an excel file to the server. When the upload completes i call a controller to import the content of this excel file to a SQL Azure database.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
            .Name("files")             
            .Multiple(false)
            .ShowFileList(true)                
            .Messages( m => m.HeaderStatusUploaded("OK"))
            .Messages( m => m.HeaderStatusUploading("Subiendo"))
            .Messages( m => m.Select("Seleccionar hoja excel"))
            .Async(a => a
                .Save("procesoImportacion", "Upload")
                .AutoUpload(true)
            )
        )
```

I would like to use SignalR to provide the process some kind of interaction.

How can i call a signalR hub instead of a controller ?

Answer (score 0):

You could call the `controller`, and inside the `action` call the `signalr` `hub`:

```
var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();

hubContext.Clients.All.sendMessage("Hello");
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but,

I don't want to send messages to all clients connected to the hub, just only to the one that uploaded the excel file. I would like to do something like this

    hubContext.Clients.Caller.sendMesage("Hello");

i think this doesn't work outside a hub.

Comment: The Clients.Caller outside a hub doesn´t compile ... The solution could be to call the hub from the kendo uploader instead of a controller ...

Comment: You could also identify your user by a unique id and add them to a group with that name, and you could call `hubContext.Clients.Group("uniqueUserId123").sendMessage("hello");`